# In Perl, how can I implement map using grep?

Tags: perl, dictionary, grep

Some time ago I was asked the “strange” question how would I implement `map` with `grep`.
Today I tried to do it, and here is what came out. Did I squeeze everything from Perl, or there are other more clever hacks?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub my_map(&@) {
    grep { $_= $_[0]->($_) } @_[1..$#_];
}

my @arr = (1,2,3,4);

#list context
say (my_map sub {$_+1}, @arr);
#scalar context
say "".my_map {$_+1} @arr;
say "the array from outside: @arr";
say "builtin map:", (map {$_+1} @arr);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure they didn't ask how to implement `grep` with `map`? That's actually useful sometimes.

```
grep { STMTs; EXPR } LIST
```

can be written as

```
map { STMTs; EXPR ? $_ : () } LIST
```

(With one difference: `grep` returns lvalues, and `map` doesn't.)

Knowing this, one can compact

```
map { $_ => 1 } grep { defined } @list
```

to

```
map { defined ? $_ => 1 : () } @list
```

(I prefer the "uncompressed" version, but the "compressed" version is probably a little faster.)

---

As for implementing `map` using `grep`, well, you can take advantage of `grep`'s looping and aliasing properties.

```
map { STMTs; EXPR } LIST
```

can be written as

```
my @rv;
grep { STMTs; push @rv, EXPR } LIST;
@rv
```

Comment: To be honest I am not sure now, as you say, may be. I never thought to do any of the two exercises just for the fun. Most probably the point of the question was to see how familiar I felt with Perl.

Answer (score 3):

My attempt at this largely pointless academic exercise is.

```
sub my_map (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @return_list;
    grep {
        push @return_list, $code->($_);
    } @_;
    return @return_list;
}
```

Using `grep` for this is a bit of a waste, because the return list of map may not be 1:1 with the input list, like `my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @array;`, you need to be more generic that using the return list of grep. The result is any looking method that allows modifying the original list would work.

```
sub my_map (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @return_list;
    push @return_list, $code->($_) for @_;
    return @return_list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean (what aspect of `map`ist to be emulated by `grep`), but a typical map-scenario could be e.g. `y = x**3`:

```
  ...
  my @list1 = (1,2,3,4,5);
  my @list2 = map $_**3, @list1;
  ...
```

With `grep`, if you had to, you could *almost* make it looke like `map` (but destroying the original list):

```
  ...
  my @list2 = grep { $_**=3; 1 } @list1;
  ...
```

by simply writing to the references of the original list elements. The *problem here* is the unwanted modification of the original list; this is what you don't want to do with `map`.

Therefore, we could just generate another list in a subroutine, modify this one and leave the original list untouched. In slight modification of [Sinan Ünür's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11190771/170194), this would read:

```
  sub gap(&@) {
     my $code = shift;
     my @list = @_;
     grep $_ = $code->($_), @list;
     @list
  }

  my @arr = (1 .. 5);

  # original map
  print join ',', map { $_**3 } @arr;
  # 1,8,27,64,125

  # grep map
  print join ',', gap { $_**3 } @arr; 
  # 1,8,27,64,125

  # test original array
  print join ',',  @arr;
  # 1,2,3,4,5 => untouched
```

Regards

rbo

Comment: `${\$_}` is the same as `$_`. You also have a precendence problem. Fixed.

Comment: @ikegami - thanks, you are right. I wasn't even aware one could modify the source list as in `map`.